# Form submited page is refreshed twice

Tags: c#, forms, web-applications, submit

I want to post data to another page.

Problem:
 The page refreshes twice. (I think once in current page and once in new one)

Here is the code:

```
protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   string URI="test";
   var data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
   data.Add("code", "1");
   string formID = "formName";
   StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
   strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + formID + "\" action=\"" + url + "\" method=\"POST\">");

   foreach (string key in data)
      strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");            

   strForm.Append("</form>");

   StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
   strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
   strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + formID + ";");
   strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
   strScript.Append("</script>");

   Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString()));
```

Comment: Because you are calling `submit` in your `script`  of `strScript.Append`.. Wrap it in a `function` instead..

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.  Would you mind removing the [tag:asp-classic] tag, please?

Comment: @Paul just did it,tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
Response.Write(strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString());
```

instead of

```
Page.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString()));
```

good luck ;)

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for
Thanks a lot